# Complex inner product custom definition proof

Tags: vector-spaces

I need to prove that a **complex vector space** has an inner product defined as

< x,y >=x<sub>1</sub>$\bar{y}$<sub>1</sub>+x<sub>2</sub>$\bar{y}$<sub>2</sub>+......+x<sub>n</sub>$\bar{y}$<sub>n</sub>

I'm doing UG, so the general method is proving using the 4 conditions:

1.< x+y,z>= < x,y>+< x,z>

2.< ax,y>=a< x,y>

3.< x,y>=< y,x>

4.< x,x>=0  iff x=0

I can prove the 1,2,4 conditions
I'm stuck at the 3rd condition, Can anyone help me?

Comment: The 3rd condition is incorrect. You need  a complex conjugate somewhere.

Comment: @copper.hat but all the other problems we proved it like that 3rd condition.What are u implying?, some like this  < x,y>=(< y,x>)' [the RHS whole bar] ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The third condition should read $\langle x,\,y\rangle=\langle y,\,x\rangle^\ast$, i.e. $\sum_ix_iy_i^\ast=(\sum_iy_ix_i^\ast)^\ast$, which is trivial. The $^\ast$'s inclusion in the condition isn't mentioned when introducing inner products on real spaces, because all reals solve $z=z^\ast$.